# Show String on control with words in diffrent colors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my app i am showing stocks quotes.

I am using a string with few stocks and its quotes and show it in a kind of marquee control.
Is it possible to print the String and show it on the control so that a few words will be in red(the descending stocks) and a few in green(the rising ones)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that very easily with a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx). [This post](http://www.ww.functionx.com/vcsharp2003/controls/richtext.htm) has a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Use rich text box and you can do something in richTextBox1_PreviewKeyDown event of rich text box

```
private void richTextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.SelectionColor != Color.Red)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why would you use `PreviewKeyDown`? Where in the question does he say *anything* about key presses?

Comment: i have just given him a suggestion to use rich text box and how he can use color schemes in that.... :)